# add mustache temple to require in require.js AMD

Tags: requirejs, mustache

In js you can load a html template in the require part while defining a module. For example:

**template file : test.html**

```
<script id="test" type="text/template">
 <div class="q-header-holder">
  <h1> {{ quizName }}</h1>
  <a href="{{ instructionLinks }}" class="q-instruction-btn">Instructions</a>
 </div>
</script>
```

in module

```
define(
 ["template/test"],
 function() {
  //.. rest of code ..
 }
);
```

But this throws error while fetching the file the filename appended with `.js` extension. Is there any way to include the template in the define block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, use the text plugin - http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text

Some extra documentation can be found here - https://github.com/requirejs/text

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i have one doubt, can i pass multiple templates into the module. when i check the document it seems to be accept only one template file.

Comment: Yeah, just list multiple templates in the dependency array.